# How to check whether the user input's type is list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build a program that can mimic the answer checking for one quiz in a class I am taking, as I got interested in wondering how the machine checks whether my answer is correct.

The quiz was to input a list that has at least one string, one integer and one float.

I think I know how to check whether the list contains the three object types. I just don't know how to check whether the input is a list since the input is always a string.

My code so far https://pastebin.com/aiMxuJwm

```
# try to create a code that can check whether the input list has at least one string, one integar and one float
alist = input('please type your answer here. Make sure it is a list and has at least one string, one integar and one float.')
element_type = []
if type(alist) == list: 
# this does not work because input always convert to str and use list() will always convert a str to list
   for element in alist:
       element_type = element_type + [type(element)]
   if str in element_type and int in element_type and float in 
element_type:
       print('You nailed it. Now you can continue to next session.')
   else:
       print('The answer is incorrect.Please try again.')
else:
   print('The answer is incorrect. Please try again.')
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `isinstance` for checking the type. For example: `lst = [1,2,3]` and then `print (isinstance(lst, list))` will print `True`

Comment: You'll need to either change the way you take user input so that they can enter multiple strings that are appended to a list, or parse the input string into a list. For example if you had the user use commas to separate their entries you can use `alist.split(',')` which would take a string like `'one,two,three'` and produce the list `['one', 'two', 'three']`

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval`, possibly only after verifying the string has some maximum length for maximum safety.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. ast.literal_eval is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like chepner suggested a way to accomplish this is to evaluate the user input using `ast.literal_eval` and then use the result in the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""
try to create a code that can check whether the input list
has at least one string, one integar and one float
"""
import ast
alist = ast.literal_eval(
    input('Please type your answer here.'
          'Make sure it is a list and has at least one string,'
          ' one integar and one float.')
)
if isinstance(alist, list): 
    element_type = list(map(type, alist))
    if str in element_type and int in element_type and float in element_type:
         print('You nailed it. Now you can continue to next session.')
         exit(0)
print('The answer is incorrect. Please try again.')
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` (in Py3) returns a string regardless of what the user types (check the docs):

```
In [166]: x = input('input please: ')
input please: testing one two three
In [167]: x
Out[167]: 'testing one two three'
In [168]: type(x)
Out[168]: str
```

If you consider this input to be a list, I suspect you are (mentally) splitting it on whitespace (or something else like commas):

```
In [169]: alist = x.split()
In [170]: alist
Out[170]: ['testing', 'one', 'two', 'three']
In [171]: type(alist)
Out[171]: list
```

The result of `split` will always be a list, though it may only contain one item.

Whether those substrings represent numbers or something else, that depends on further testing.  For now they are just strings, not floats or integers.

Testing for string, float and/or integer will need to consider the following cases:

```
In [173]: x = input('input please: ')
input please: one 2 2.34
In [174]: x
Out[174]: 'one 2 2.34'
In [175]: alist = x.split()
In [176]: alist
```

a string that doesn't represent a float:

```
Out[176]: ['one', '2', '2.34']
In [177]: float(alist[0])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-177-aa7191219228> in <module>()
----> 1 float(alist[0])

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'one'
In [178]: float(alist[1])
Out[178]: 2.0
In [179]: float(alist[2])
Out[179]: 2.34
```

One that is a float, but not an integer:

```
In [180]: int(alist[2])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-180-6d641dbd1dad> in <module>()
----> 1 int(alist[2])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.34'
```

As a first cut I'd write a function that takes a string, and applies the tests with appropriate `try/except` wrapper, and returns some sort of `type` indicator.  Then apply that function to the strings of `alist`.

There may be other ways of doing this testing, but this would be a start.

---

The key here is making sure you know what objects are at each step.  When do you have strings?  list of strings?  strings that represent a float or integer?

---

Another approach is to think about what a list containing strings and numbers looks like - as a list, and in its string representation:

```
In [188]: alist = ['one', 2, 2.34]
In [189]: str(alist)
Out[189]: "['one', 2, 2.34]"
```

`json` is good tool for representing simple data structures like this that various languages can handle:

```
In [191]: import json
In [192]: json.dumps(alist)
Out[192]: '["one", 2, 2.34]'
In [193]: json.loads(_)
Out[193]: ['one', 2, 2.34]
```

---

Others have suggested `ast`.  That like `json` may be pickier about input that you want:

```
In [204]: x = input('input please: ')
input please: ['one', 2, 2.34]
In [205]: x
Out[205]: "['one', 2, 2.34]"
In [206]: ast.literal_eval(x)
Out[206]: ['one', 2, 2.34]
In [207]: x = input('input please: ')
input please: 'one', 2, 2.34
In [208]: x
Out[208]: "'one', 2, 2.34"
In [209]: ast.literal_eval(x)
Out[209]: ('one', 2, 2.34)
```

If I omit the `[]` it returns a tuple, not a list.  If I don't quote the string, I get an error.  If I quote the number, it remains a string.  I have to use commas, not spaces.

### Py2

A potential point of confusion is that Py2 has 2 input functions, one that returns a string like the Py3 `input`, and one that interprets that string:

```
>>> x = input('test:')
test:[1,2,3]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
>>> type(x)
<type 'list'>
>>> x = rawinput('test:')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'rawinput' is not defined
>>> x = raw_input('test:')
test:[1,2,3]
>>> x
'[1,2,3]'
>>> type(x)
<type 'str'>
```

The `help` for `input` is:

> Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt))

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. My goal is to test whether the input is a list so your suggestion doesn't work well for me. However, you gave me some great ideas about entering info to Python. I will definitely try json in the future. Thank you.

Comment: How do you define a list?

Comment: It's just the list type in basic python. This: <class 'list'>. I was wondering how the machine tests whether students' answers are right. The instructor asked us to enter a list. That is why I want to try to replicate it using python.

Comment: A possible point of confusion is that `input` for Py2 does `eval` the string.  The Py3 `input` returns a string, which requires some sort of evaluation, such as with the recommended `ast`, or my more pedantic parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Use argparse with an argument of type int or specify `nargs='+'` for another argument parameter for a list of ints:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Some input")
# int type
parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", dest="input", default=None, type=int, help="Input argument")
# list of ints type
parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", dest="input", default=None, type=int, nargs='+', help="Input argument")
```

Comment: This doesn't handle interactive user input.  It parses the command line input, looking for something like '--input 1 2 3'.